# How can I run protractor tests against IE 11 during a TFS build

Tags: powershell, tfs, protractor, internet-explorer-11, tfsbuild

I have been trying to run protractor UI tests as a part of our TFS Build for several days now and I'm stuck. I use powershell to kick off protractor against Chrome and then against IE. I know protractor supports concurrent testing, but this is my setup right now. When I log into the build VM and execute the powershell script both IE and Chrome open and the tests run beautifully. However, this is not the case during the TFbuild. If I RDP to the build VM during a build I see no Chrome windows or IE windows. It seems that both of the browsers are running in the background as I can see their processes running in Task Manager. In this case the Chrome tests execute just fine, however, IE doesn't seem to be able handle this background (headless) state so well. The IE tests take forever and when it's finished they've all failed. What can I do to fix this? Is there a way to have IE open normally, that is, not in the background? Is this issue because of TFS or is it a powershell thing? Here is my script:

```
    #get arguments
    Param(
        $browserName
    )

    $testLocation = "C:\path\to\tests\on\build\machine"
    #start the webdriver 
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression "webdriver-manager start" } -Name webdriver
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

    Set-Location -Path $testLocation
    #pipe to output so powershell will wait on the process to complete.
    protractor conf.js --browser="$browserName" | Write-Output
```

In my build template I am using a RunScript activity and pointing it at this script.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the down vote. I'd be happy to improve my question.

Comment: Did you get any error message from the IE test? Did you try another version of IE, like IE 10? Some settings in IE 11 are different from the previous IE versions, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/16/using-internet-explorer-11-and-not-able-to-record-a-web-performance-test-successfully.aspx, so you can try with another IE version, like IE 10 to see whether the issue persists.